# Open folder on portable device with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

1. General goal: create a desktop shortcut to a folder buried the file structure of my phone's SD card (connected via USB).  Note, this is on a work computer, so I can't do anything to crazy. 
   I tried using normal shortcuts to no avail, so I decided to try using a batch if I can't use a shortcut.  If using a shortcut is possible or there is a better option than a batch let me know.
2. Specific question: How can I open a folder using a batch file?  I can manually open explorer, paste the address into the bar and go there, so there should be a way to mimic this, but so far my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Attempts:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "Computer\My S4\Phone\Android\data\com.dropbox.android\files\scratch\"
explorer Computer/My S4/Phone/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch
start "" "Computer\My S4\Phone\Android\data\com.dropbox.android\files\scratch\"
start Computer\My S4\Phone\Android\data\com.dropbox.android\files\scratch
```

Comment: To open a folder: `start c:\temp`

Comment: This isn't possible. Your phone is on a totally separate file system that you can't access from the command line.

Comment: @SomethingDark If I open explorer manually and paste the address into the address bar, it works.  Is there a way to get the computer to do the same thing as if I was doing it manually?

Comment: You can try using Autohotkey.

Comment: @SomethingDark It looks like that requires installing other software, which I can't do on my work computer.  Do you know of any native windows functionality for programmatically navigating to certain folder?  I don't really even need to see the files as much as always copy the same two files to the same location.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to open an MTP device folder directly in the Windows Explorer window on `Windows 7 x64`.

Here is steps:

1. Open Windows Explorer with the `My Computer` folder, for example:

   - `start "" "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"`
   - `start "" "shell:::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"`
   - `explorer "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"`
   - `explorer "shell:::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"`

   The complete list of GUIDs you can find on the internet, for example: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3123-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-10-a.html
2. Attach the MTP device and enable File Transfer mode in the device. It must be shown in the `My Computer` window as a portable device entry.
3. Drag and Drop the MTP device entry icon to the Desktop.
4. Open any notepad, for the instance, Windows notepad: `Win+R` -> `notepad`
5. Drag and drop the desktop icon into notepad window.
   At the end of the notepad text would be something like:
   `::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_0e8d&pid_201d&mi_00#7&1084e14&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}` (spaces removed).
   You can cleanup the spaces between characters by copy the string into another instance of the notepad and replace them through the `Ctrl+H` to nothing.
6. Now you can open the MTP device folder directly:
   `start "" "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_0e8d&pid_201d&mi_00#7&1084e14&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\<your-local-path-to-folder>"`

There is a wait timeout, so the Windows Explorer window might not open immediately.

To generate a shortcut to target folder you can use `make_shortcut.vbs` script from here: https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/vbs/

For example:

```
>
make_shortcut.vbs myphonecamera.lnk "shell:::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_0e8d&pid_201d&mi_00#7&1084e14&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SD-card Samsung\DCIM\Camera"
```

Now you can click `myphonecamera.lnk` to open the folder or use the Windows Explorer:

```
>
explorer myphonecamera.lnk
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an addition to [Andry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65997169/150978):

It can be very complicated to get the whole path to an MTP folder like
`::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_03de&pid_21e7&mi_00#6&a5ebb37&1&0000#{6ac27878-a6fc-2155-ea85-f98f491d4f33}\{E4FC4EA5-FFFF-FFFF-0000-000000000000}`

To get the path do the following:

1. In Windows Explorer select the folder on the MTP device you want to get the path of.
2. Open it's context menu and select `Copy`
3. Open in Explorer a folder on your PC, open the context menu on a free area and select `Paste Shortcut`
4. Now we need a too that can read `.lnk` files. I have used the tool [LECmd](https://github.com/EricZimmerman/LECmd). Execute `LECmd.exe -f <path to the .lnk file created in step 3>`.

You will get a lot of content printed to the console. The interesting part is the `Parsing Path` next to the end.

In my case it was `::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_03de&pid_21e7&mi_00#6&a5ebb37&1&0000#{6ac27878-a6fc-2155-ea85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{10001,,21003612160}\{E4FC4EA5-FFFF-FFFF-0000-000000000000}`

Now we are close, unfortunately the path shown above can not be used because it contains an invalid part: `\SID-{10001,,21003612160}`. Remove that part and you can open the explorer in that MTP folder using

`start "" "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_03de&pid_21e7&mi_00#6&a5ebb37&1&0000#{6ac27878-a6fc-2155-ea85-f98f491d4f33}\{E4FC4EA5-FFFF-FFFF-0000-000000000000}"`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `Computer` which is not a device name, try to use `\\?\` or `\\.\` which both refer to the local computer.