# How to open a folder using batch code or powershell code, from a connected phone?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

In windows file explorer, if I go here

`This PC\My S23 Ultra\Internal storage\DCIM\Camera`

it opens the folder on the phone. But I want to automate this using a shortcut. If I try a windows shortcut, it considers this invalid path and won't let me make it. So then I thought batch file. So then I tried

```
explorer.exe "This PC\My S23 Ultra\Internal storage\DCIM\Camera"
```

But it opens the wrong location. Opens "Documents" path.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397348/open-folder-on-portable-device-with-batch-file perhaps? Not sure if it's still applicable in later Windows

Comment: I would propably look for solutions that leverage the Shell.Application COM object. This seems to be the way how alternative file explorer applications (like Total Commander) access files on a phone. An indication for that is when you copy a file from the phone, the shell progress dialog pops up instead of the applications own progress dialog.

Comment: [Already decided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68872329/powershell-how-to-list-files-and-get-their-info-on-usb-devices-that-dont-hav/76116689#76116689)

Comment: "You're almost there. You can not use PowerShell cmdlets to browse MTP devices." - Terrible that this is not implemented.